# Is it possible to show Google Adsense on Shiny Apps?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to include Google Adense ads in a Shiny app on shinyapps.io.
On Google Adsense it is possible to create ads without specifying a website, since an xxx.shinyapps.io URL is not supported.

The documentation simply says to include the HTML code within the  of the page. So I simply saved an html file and used includeHTML() in the ui.
The  is included in the resulting page, if I check from Chrome, but still the ads are not showing.

Did anyone ever tried and succeed?

Thanks,
Fabio